# XCopy Not Preserving Folder Hierarchy?

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I've created a batch script to backup certain folders and the sub-folders within them. I'm not overly comfortable with batch scripting yet, and I've run into a problem - When I try to backup my Firefox Portable profile (it's in a RAMDisk), it copies the contents of the App, Data, and Other folders, and throws them all into one folder together, without their respective parent directories.

Here are the folders I see after extracting the backed up .7z file and navigating to 2011_07_28\ffportablebackups:

- AppInfo
- DefaultData
- Firefox
- Help
- plugins
- profile
- settings
- Source
- readme.txt (file)

Would a kind soul point out where I went wrong? Here's the code:

```
@echo off
:: variables
set dropboxLocation="%USERPROFILE%\Dropbox"
set sharedObjFolder="%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects"
set FFPortable="R:\FirefoxPortable"
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y

echo Copying Files...
for /d %%f in (""%sharedObjFolder%\*"") do (
    echo "%%f\chat.kongregate.com"
    %backupcmd% "%%f\chat.kongregate.com" "%temp%\kongbackups\chat.kongregate.com"
    if exist "%%f\kongregate.com" %backupcmd% "%%f\kongregate.com" "%temp%\kongbackups\kongregate.com"
)

echo Backing up FF Portable...
for /d %%g in (""%FFPortable%\*"") do (
    echo "%%g"
    %backupcmd% "%%g" "%temp%\ffportablebackups"
)

echo Compressing Files...
7za a %temp%\kongbackups\%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%.7z "%temp%\kongbackups"
7za a %temp%\ffportablebackups\%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%.7z "%temp%\ffportablebackups"

echo Moving Files...
mkdir %dropboxLocation%
move "%temp%\kongbackups\*.7z" "%dropboxLocation%\Backups\Kongregate_Backup_Saves\Laptop"
mkdir "%dropboxLocation%\Backups\FF_Portable
move "%temp%\ffportablebackups\*.7z" "%dropboxLocation%\Backups\FF_Portable"
rmdir /S /Q "%temp%\kongbackups"
rmdir /S /Q "%temp%\ffportablebackups"

echo.
echo.
echo Script created by Matthew Ammann, revised by Ventero
echo.
echo Backup Complete!
@pause
```

Comment: be more precise in your question. Debug your batch down to a few lines that show the error.

Comment: The log I generated from this batch file reveals no errors or problems that I can see. I'd post it, but I'm not sure if FF Portable stores encrypted keys as filenames that I shouldn't be sharing.